# Error with loop in Google Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script to delete columns by passing an array of column numbers getting error

`Cannot find method deleteColumns((class))`

I'm pretty sure this is the problem

```
for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){
      sheet.deleteColumns(arr[i]);
      };
```

Thanks for any help on this

```
function DMC_n(){
   DMC('Elements', [1,2]);  
}

function DMC(shtName, arr){
  var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shtName);
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length -1; i++){
      sheet.deleteColumns(arr[i]);
      };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `DMC()` defines three parameters, where the last one, "arr", is not given from your function call:

```
DMC('Elements', [1,2]);
```

So the third argument is undefined.

Comment: Ops.  Thanks, I repurposed a script and left that in there by mistake.  I edited my question.  Now getting error `Cannot find method deleteColumns((class))`

Comment: The issue is just as says. The object `sheet` does not have that method. Why don't you try console logging sheet and see what's inside?

Comment: This was the problem `(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++)` changed to `(var i = 0; i <= arr.length -1; i++)` and now works